# Ajax "get" works in Firefox, but not in Microsoft Edge, Opera or Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, get, opera

Just as the title says; I'm having issues with Ajax not working in Microsoft Edge, Opera and Chrome, though the code has not been tested on Safari. I'm not sure what versions of each browser I'm running, but the laptop was a gift from Christmas a year ago. Both websites have signed security certificates, so I already ruled that out.

....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


myUrl = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=United%20States&adminDistrict=Washington&locality=Redmond&postalCode=98052&addressLine=1%20Microsoft%20Way&maxResults=1&key=AnbywjkHp03Y6rtT_itX-o1G17Ji5O5ADMZjFGklQhu1SAX_FClVS5AT9Uyj9xtP";

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=utf-8');
          }
        },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log( "Sample of data:", response.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }})
    .fail(function() { console.log("You done gone and broke it again."); });
```

....

Does anyone know how to address this issue?